# Updated a table in dbml file and all webcontrols throw error

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, web-config, web-controls

I had to make some changes in one of my table and so to refresh the table in my dbml file, I just removed and readded that particular table by dragging it from server explorer of vs 2010. After that, all of a sudden, all my web controls started giving me error "The name '*_*_' does not exist". They all work when the tag prefix is asp, but all of them with my own tag stopped working. I checked the web.config file and it has the correct name added in the control with the correct tag name. It was working till I remove and then add a table from dbml file.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often when you update a table in the .dbml file the auto-generator changes the pluralization of the objects in question. You will want to check to make sure that the new table in the .dbml table is not adding or subtracting (s) or (ies) in a manner that is inconsistent with the way it was before the change.

Comment: Ok, where exactly should I check for these inconsistencies. Like in dbml.css file? as the controls in the aspx pages seems to be correct.

Comment: @Ratan: I would start with the first exception. If this happens you should be able to identify it with the intellisense. You'll see your table and it will have a slightly different name. You should be able to rename the objects using the properties window of the tables having problems in the .dbml file.

Comment: Yeah, when I opened the dbml cs file, the error message was "Error 98 Ambiguity between 'ProjectName.Model.organization._isSite' and 'ProjectName.Model.organization._isSite'" On checking the code, I found that for the table I edited, it has added one more definition for _isSite. The two definitions are: private bool _isSite; and the other one is private System.Nullable<bool> @__isSite; The column is a nullable column in my table. Why did it add two and which one is correct. Thanks a lot!